# How to use other types with UIMA ConceptMapper

Tags: nlp, uima

I have been successfully using UIMA ConceptMapper with a dictionary that I built. I set the TokenAnnotation parameter to uima.tt.TokenAnnotation and the SpanFeatureStructure parameter to uima.tt.SentenceAnnotation (based on the reference example).  These types are I believe coming from the OpenNLP parser.  But I also do another parse using medkatp and would like to use their types.  So far I have not figured out how to do that.  If I change either of these two parameters the whole thing fails saying that it cannot find the type.

I've searched for hours on the net but have found no examples of ConceptMapper that use anything except these two types.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.  I've searched everywhere but can find no answer.

Answer (score 0):

> These types are I believe coming from the OpenNLP parser.

These types are defined in the component descriptor (usually, in the desc folder), under the tag `<typeSystemDescription>`

> But I also do another parse using medkatp and would like to use their types.

If you want to use other types (from other UIMA components, or your own types), you need to define them wherever you use them (meaning: in every component descriptor where you need it, under the tag `<typeSystemDescription>`).